# Identify the rain cover

Tags: equipment-protection, rain, snow

What kind of rain cover this photographer is using?

I couldn't find anything similar on [B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Rain-Capes-Covers-Slickers/ci/3313/N/4075788778) and Adorama.

[image]
Photo: [Stylecaster, by Jenny Norris](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151225335746012)

Comment: something from his kitchen?

Comment: I don't think so, it looks like that is something tightly fitted around the camera...

Comment: You can do a lot with Gorilla Tape and large size Zip-lock freezer bags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SNOWY STREET STYLE AT NEW YORK FASHION WEEK: OUTSIDE RAG & BONE**

None of the photographers appear to be the same, but this is the event where your photo came from, and the general style of cover looks the same. Just perhaps more tightly wrapped in later photos. Maybe not..
Somebody may well have been selling them on the spot - which would account for the similarities.
 [Photo here](http://cache.daylife.com/imageserve/02Tt6Us49zeK3/690x458.jpg)

=>

[image]

[On this page](http://stylecaster.com/snowy-street-style-york-fashion-week-rag-bone/)

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a cheap plastic rain cover that can be purchased over sites like ebay or amazon. You have to search for the terms **camera rain cover**.  These are cheap ones though they only stop rain to a certain amount.

- [Ebay rain cover](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ESSENTIAL-2X-RAIN-COVER-FOR-CANON-NIKON-PENTAX-DSLR-CAMERAS-2-CLEANING-CLOTHS-/271150907030?pt=US_Camera_Cases_Bags&hash=item3f21da7e96)
- [optech rain sleeve](http://optechusa.com/rainsleeve.html)

[image: rain cover]

Comment: It's a shame they don't include a Canon DSLR with their $10 rain cover, but at least they make this point clear in the image.

Comment: But it looks like that is something tightly fitted around the camera...

Comment: @MattGrum The camera (body) is obviously not included, but it doesn't say anything about the lens, so buy the rain cover and get the lens. Supply the body yourself.

Answer (score -2):

It's called a Rain Sleeve. They're about $6.